# Link SQL query result in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server

I have a sql query witch search students name from sql database it shows results now i want to link each result get 
    `http url www.tlss.edu.pk/result.php?r=1` 
if 
    `Sr_=1`
my SQL Query is

```
<?php
include 'form.html';
$r1=$_GET["r"];
$n1=$_GET["n"];
// Create connection
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","chumspai_tlss","Tls121","chumspai_tlsResult");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
  echo $n1;
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM nursery_blue_ WHERE students_names like '%$n1%'");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{

echo '<pre>';
    print_r ($row['sr_']. '.'. $row['students_names']);
    echo '</pre>';
  }
    ?>
```

Comment: add an anchor in loop ans set your link values

Comment: how to add anchor i am new to php please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add an link in your loop and if you have any condition add condition for show link

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
   echo "<a href='http://www.tlss.edu.pk/result.php?r=".$row['sr_']."'>".$row['students_names']."</a>";
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you need to try like

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
     //print_r ($row['sr_']. '.'. $row['students_names']);
     if($row['sr_'] == 1) {
        echo "<a href='www.tlss.edu.pk/result.php?r=".$row['sr_']."'>"
              .$row['students_names']."</a>";
     }
 }
```

If you want all the results then you can remove the `if` condition here.

Comment: if `$row['sr_']` is `1` then only anchor tag will appear as you mentioned in your question

Comment: as you have asked to get only when sr_ is `1` then it will get the result orelse you can remove the `if` condition to get all the results